# how to implement in column of table an attribute that implement interface?

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine

I have a entities:

```
class UserEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="?????")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="?????", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     * @var RolEntityInterface
     */
    private $rolEntity;
```

```
class OneRolEntity implements RolEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;
```

```
class TwoRolEntity implements RolEntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @var int
     */
     private $id;
```

and tables, 
**users** (with columns: id, rol_id) 
** one_rol** (with columns: id)
** two_rol** (with columns: id)

I need the column **rol_id** of **users** table to be a foreign key to table **one_rol** or a foreign key to table **two_rol** depending on the entity that is embedded in the attribute **$rolEntity** of **UserEntity**.

is it possible to implement this?
and how to complete the annotations:
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="**?????**")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="**?????**")

NOTE: I use phpmyadmin.

Comment: You can't. OneRolEntity will be a table and TwoRolEntity will be another table. In UserEntity you can create a foreign key only for one key, so this must be clearly. You would neet a OneToOne-Relation for both RoleEntities or create a manual relation table where you have an integer column "role_id" with ID from OneRoleEntity or TwoRoleEntity and an char column "role_type" where you point to "one_role" or "two_role". But then you need to manage this relation on your self.

Comment: thanks, your answer was useful.